# How to add new contact numbers to existing contacts?

Tags: android

I have the following code to update a contact number, but the problem is, it only replaces an existing one

I would like to ADD a new number and keep the numbers that already exists in the contact,  if it has 2 contact numbers, I would like to be able to add a third one even if it already has a MOBILE_NUMBER in the contact, I would like to be able to add a new one.

I tried a lot of codes here in stackoverflow but I couldn't find any to do it.

from what I've been searching, When you add a new number to an existing contact, you actually create a new contact and associate to the same contact_id. but I couldn't do it.

```
public static void updateContactNumber (String contactId, String newNumber, Activity act) 
       {

            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 
            String selectPhone = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  + 
                            Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + Phone.TYPE + "=?";
            String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{contactId, String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE_WORK)}; 


            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
                    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "44441111")
                    .build()); 



            try {
                act.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi grego i also got same problems ..So if you have find any solution then please help me. Thanks

Comment: Any intent? Any help?